# How do I use the AppGlideModule in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-glide

Using the Glide library on Xamarin.Android, I was hoping someone could shed some light on how to use the AppGlideModule. According to the documentation, I need to register my custom ModelLoader using the AppGlideModule.

Here is a link to the example in the Glide documentation:
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/tut/custom-modelloader.html#writing-the-modelloader

Here is my custom AppGlideModule class:

```
public class MyCustomGlideModule : AppGlideModule
{
    public override void ApplyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ApplyOptions(context, builder);
    }

    public override void RegisterComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry)
    {
        registry.Prepend(
            Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Java.IO.OutputStream)),
            Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Drawable)),
            new MyCustomImageStreamModelLoaderFactory()
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's necessary, but if you'd like to see the classes I made for the ModelLoader, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: So, what's your problem? Have you followed the three steps to do?

Comment: I'm pretty confident I have. I believe my issue lies with the "@GlideModule" annotation (is that the correct terminology?). In their example, they put that @GlideModule above the AppGlideModule class, and I guess Java knows to connect that to Glide somehow. It's just that I don't know how to do that with Xamarin C#.

Comment: To add, I've tried adding [Annotation("GlideModule")] and also [Annotation("@GlideModule")] above my AppGlideModule class to no avail.

Comment: You can't use this function in Xamarin, because in this Xamarin.Android lib,[here is its .jar file which is used to binding](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android/blob/master/Glide/Jars/glide-4.1.1.jar). In the .jar file, there is no `com.bumptech.glide.annotation`, so it doesn't have `GlideModule`. You can found one `GlideModule`, but it is in `com.bumptech.glide.module` folder, and it is add `@Deprecated`. I have found several hours, you can also check if there is a `GlideModule` you can use. So I think, you need binding the glide .jar file by yourself, or you can use .aar.

Comment: Please tell me you are using [this](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android) , if so, you maybe really can't use the `GlideModule` like java.

Comment: @JoeLv yes, I am using the project you linked. Thank you for looking into this. I will search for another method to accomplish what I need until this is worked out =]

Comment: @hellaandrew have you found out how to use GlideModule annotation?

Comment: @SanifSS I have not. I am convinced that as of this time, annotations are a feature currently unsupported by Xamarin. This seems to be only an Android Studio/Java feature unfortunately =[

Answer (score 1):

Old question but here is the trick.  You will need to create an Android/Java library that contains an AppGlideModule wrapper.  This library contains nothing else and is simply used to generate the GlideApp class.  It needs to contain a static instance of your final AppGlideModule.  Basically, it will look like this :

```
@GlideModule
public class XamarinGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    public static AppGlideModule InjectedModule;

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        if(InjectedModule != null) {
            InjectedModule.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);
        }
    }
}
```

You will then need to wrap this library in an Android binding library.  Nothing is worthy of mention in this step, simply drop your built AAR in the binding project, add the matching version of the Glide Nuget and build.

You can then add a reference to that binding library in your app project.  In your Android Application class, you will need to setup the InjectedModule static property to inject your Xamarin implementation.  You must do this before any call to Glide, something similar to this :

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();

    XamarinGlideModule.InjectedModule = new MyLoaderModule();
    var temp = GlideApp.Get(this); // Init Glide, it will register your Xamarin module
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there's one more option to use custom glide module from C# code. Just install package of this project:

https://github.com/KDD-Digital-Healthcare-GmbH/Kdd.Glide.AppModuleInjector

NOTE: if you need custom AppModule for glide just to accept self-signed certificates, you can install this package as well, it already has implementation of such module:

https://github.com/KDD-Digital-Healthcare-GmbH/Kdd.Glide.UnsafeUrlLoadingAppGlideModule

Comment: Yeah, that is just what I described above in a Nuget.